# How to extract a rar file that contains multiple folders with overwrite in c# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, extract, overwrite, winrar

I want to extract  a rar file to a location .
The thing is , that the rar file contains 4 folders, and the extraction fails.
I need to extract all files and folders in my rar to the location folder.
And extract the files that doesn't exist.

What I have done so far :

```
Process winrar = new Process();
winrar.StartInfo.FileName = WinrarPath + @"\unrar.exe";
winrar.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
winrar.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
winrar.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
winrar.ErrorDataReceived += new 
DataReceivedEventHandler(winrar_ErrorDataReceived);
string src = downloadFilPath; // directory , not the file itself
string des = @"D:\"
winrar.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("x -o+ {0} {1}", src, des);
winrar.Start();
winrar.WaitForExit();
```

It works great , if the rar file contains only one folder .
The problem is for a rar file that contains more than one folder in it.
Maybe it will help you give me a solution for my problem.

Thanks , 
Shuki

Comment: May be you can simply try to delete the destination folder first?

Comment: Files that are not in the archive would disappear if you did that. Since the OP only speaks of overwriting existing files (with their new counterparts from the archive), I don't think that's what he wants.

Comment: Ah OK, I see, it is possible

Answer (score 4):

Use the command line switch "-o+" to specify automatic overwriting. In your example, the arguments line would become:

```
winrar.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("x -o+ \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", src, des);
```

However, depending on how portable and reliable you need this application to be, you might want to consider using a native .NET library for RAR and other archive handling. One such library I've used successfully in the past is [SharpCompress](http://sharpcompress.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fcca5e95eafd#README).

From the WinRAR help file:

> **Switch -O[+|-] - set the overwrite mode**
>
> ---
>
> This switch can be used both when extracting and updating archived
>   files. Following modes are available:
>
> -o Ask before overwrite (default for extracting files)
>
> -o+ Overwrite all (default for updating archived files);
>
> -o- Skip existing files.

Comment: if my rar file contains only one folder it works. 
but if it contains several folders , it is a problem

Comment: When you say "didn't work", it's quite useful to mention the specific error message you get. I can't really help you if all the feedback I get is "a problem"...

Comment: I edited my answer to include double quotes around the source and destination path. Pertaining to your comment about not working with multiple folders - have you actually tried to perform the operation manually using the command prompt before simulating the operation from C#? In those rare cases where executing an external executable from your C# code is the best solution, I've found that manually entering the command and seeing what happens is a lot less frustrating.